# an action-noun for putting into practice some individual qualities

Tags: word-request

As far as I know, the phrase "direct result" should be used in English for some actions.

For example:

> "The economic recession was a direct result of the government's
> **implementation** of that detrimental policy."
>
> "This discovery was a direct result of their **research**."

Both 'implementation' and 'research' imply some kind of actions.

However, it wouldn't sound right if I applied 'direct result' for a non-action noun:

> "His ability to locate that place so fast was a direct result of the
> **map** that he had with him."

Here I have a similar problem. I have a sentence listing some personal qualities of some individual and stating that individual's success based on those qualities:

> "His success was a direct result of such individual qualities like
> self-confidence, persistence and amazing speaking skills."

I want to keep the phrase "a direct result" in it, but I don't know which action-noun to use. I was thinking about 'utilization':

> "His success was a direct result of **utilization** of such individual
> qualities like self-confidence, persistence and amazing speaking
> skills.

but I think it sounds too technical.

Comment: Why do you think "His success was a direct result of individual qualities like self-confidence, persistence and amazing speaking skills"? Though "a direct result of such individual qualities as" would also be ok.

Comment: @user3169 - "_Why do you think_" - I don't know. I am not a native English speaker, so I don't really know. If what you have suggested sounds okay in English than I am more than happy. It's just that somebody told me before that 'direct result' can also be of actions or a process. I might have been mislead by that. So, the phrase 'direct result' then can also work fine with non-action nouns  ('self-confidence', 'persistence' and 'skills')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, *like* should be replaced by *as*:

> His success was a direct result of *such* individual qualities *as* self-confidence, persistence and amazing speaking skills.

This is a modified word order of the phrase *such as*.

It would be more economical to say

> His success was due to his self-confidence, persistence, and speaking skills.

If you insist on the longer structure, instead of *utilization of*, you might consider *use of* or *application of*.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think using the phrase 'direct result of' without any action noun would also work (it was suggested by @user3169 in the comment above: "His success was a direct result of such individual qualities as self-confidence, persistence and amazing speaking skills")?

Comment: Yes, that was the phrasing in my answer.